# Trying To Update GUI Within Thread (Started From BackgroundWorker)

Tags: vb.net, multithreading

I am having issues working with GUI updates on different threads.  My scenario is this:

I have a main form with a single checkbox on it.  In the `Form_Load` event I start a background worker.  In the `BackgroundWorker_DoWork` event I call a new class which in turn starts a new thread.  From this thread I am trying to set the `Checked` state of the checkbox on Form1 but without any luck.

So far I have the following code sample:

```
Public Class Form1
    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Try
            BackgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync()

        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.ToString)
        End Try
    End Sub

    Private Sub BackgroundWorker1_DoWork(sender As Object, e As System.ComponentModel.DoWorkEventArgs) Handles BackgroundWorker1.DoWork
        Try

            Do While Not BackgroundWorker1.CancellationPending = True
                Dim cl As New HandleClient
                Me.Invoke(Sub() Checkbox1.Checked = True)
            Loop

        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.ToString)
        End Try
    End Sub
End Class

Public Class HandleClient

    Public Sub startClient()
        Dim ctThread As Threading.Thread = New Threading.Thread(AddressOf start)
        ctThread.Start()
    End Sub

    Private Sub start()
        While (True)
            Try
                ...
                ..

            Catch ex As Exception
                    Form1.Invoke(Sub() Form1.Checkbox1.Checked = False) '<== Fails here
            End Try
        End While
    End Sub
End Class
```

I have tried using ThreadSafe calls and setting properties through a separate class but I either get an error stating that I can't use BeginInvoke or the Checkbox just doesn't update (without error).

Any help appreciated thanks.

Comment: Whoops sorry - that was code left over from something I was trying.  I attempted to set the flag from within a separate class.  I have updated my post.

Comment: so why are you creating another new thread inside `BackgroundWorker.DoWork`?  move your time consuming task to there and it should work fine

Comment: The reason it is setup this way is because when I launch my form I start a background worker to listen for incoming socket connections from many clients.  Each time a socket connection is made, it starts a new worker thread to accept incoming messages and continues to listen on that thread.  When the connection from the client is dropped, it throws an exception and that's when I want to show a 'disconnected' flag on the main form.  That is why I have a thread inside a background worker.  I'm not sure any other way to set that up.  I assumed this is how it needed to work.

Comment: you should add that (fairly important) detail to the actual question.  When the Listener BGW detects a new connection you could use the ReportProgress overload to start a new sibling BGW for that connection.  I would almost certainly write a wrapper class to store info about each BGW (which port, timeout etc), store them in a collection and I would not use an interactive control for the status.

Comment: ...it also appears that you are trying to use the default form instance - that almost never turns out well with threads

Comment: @Plutonix Thanks for your comments and sorry for the late reply.  I am interested in your comments about using the ReportProgress overload and creating a wrapper to handle many clients.  Do you think it's possible you could provide a small example to guide me in the right direction?  It would be greatly appreciated - thanks.

Comment: @Plutonix How many active connections do you think a server could handle?  With your example above, do you think I could support around 1000 clients connected at once?  I am trying to create a scenario similar to TeamViewer where it detects client's connection status' pretty much instantly.

Comment: You might be getting ahead of yourself (or us).  The post (and comments) are regarding the effective creation of threads.  I just created 50 BGWs to rifle thru a large folder of files and report to a listbox and the CPU monitor didnt budge.  Server loads are something different and something we cant know without many many more details - ATM and Credit Card networks handle gobs of transactions though

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure why you are starting a new thread from a background worker that has already started a new thread for the worker. Seems like an extra unneeded thread. The backgroundworker worker thread can't update controls that are owned by the UI thread which is the same reason why your new handle client thread can't update it either. With the background object you can update the UI thread by raising the `ProgressChanged` event of the background worker and place the updating code into the method that handles the event.

```vb
Public Class Form1
    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Try
            BackgroundWorker1.WorkerReportsProgress = true
            BackgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync()

        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.ToString)
        End Try
    End Sub

    Private Sub BackgroundWorker1_DoWork(sender As Object, e As System.ComponentModel.DoWorkEventArgs) Handles BackgroundWorker1.DoWork

        Dim worker As BackgroundWorker = CType(sender, BackgroundWorker)

        Try

            Do While Not worker.CancellationPending = True
                ' Do the thing that is in the Try block of the HandleClient
                Try
                    ' ...
                    ' ..
                    ' Using a value of 1 for true, since you used False in the catch statement
                    worker.ReportProgress(1)
                    ' Or you can use the overloaded method
                    worker.ReportProgress(0, True)
                Catch ex As Exception
                    ' Form1.Invoke(Sub() Form1.Checkbox1.Checked = False) '<== Fails here
                    ' Using a value of 0 for false
                    worker.ReportProgress(0)
                    ' Or you can use the overloaded method
                    worker.ReportProgress(0, False)
                End Try

            Loop

        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.ToString)
        End Try
    End Sub

    Private Sub backgroundWorker1_ProgressChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As ProgressChangedEventArgs) Handles backgroundWorker1.ProgressChanged
        ' If you used the overloaded method, you can delete this case statement
        Select Case e.ProgressPercentage
            Case 0
                Form1.Checkbox1.Checked = True
            Case 1
                Form1.Checkbox1.Checked = False
            Case Else 
                Form1.Checkbox1.CheckState = CheckState.Indeterminate
        End Select

        ' Or just use the userstate as mention in the comments
        Form1.Checkbox1.Checked = DirectCast(e.UserSate, Boolean)

    End Sub 

End Class
```

Comment: It may be worth pointing out that rather than hijacking the percentProgress parameter for another purpose, there is an [overload of ReportProgess](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a3zbdb1t%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) which takes an object as the second parameter which you can use to pass other data, including an instance of a class with however many parameters of whatever type is needed.

Comment: @AndrewMorton I thought just using the progress amount would be easier to understand, but I went ahead and added the use of the overloaded method too.

Comment: You ought to use `DirectCast(e.UserState, Boolean)`. Have you forgotten to use Option Strict On? ;)

Comment: I have updated my comments in the above post to explain my reasoning behind the way I have set this up.